# If the matrix $A$ is similar to an upper triangular matrix $T$, both with real entries, which must be true?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A\in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ is similar to some upper triangular matrix $T\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$. $P_A$ means polynomial characteristic for matrix $A$.

Then:
a. $P_A$ is product of polynomial of  degree one with complex coefficients.
b. $P_A$ is product of polynomial of  degree one with real coefficients.
c. matrices  $A^2$ and $T^2$ are similar.

First of all, lets note that similar matrices have equal characteristic polynomials.
  a. is not true:
$T= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 \\
0&1 \end{array} \right]$
$P_T=(1-\lambda)^2$
b. is not true (the same reasons as a.)
c. This one is too difficult for me - Could you help me, please ?

What about correctness of a. and b. ?

Comment: $(1-\lambda)^2$ **is** a "product of polynomial of degree one with complex coefficients," since it's $(1-\lambda)(1-\lambda)$, which is a product of polynomials with degree one. the claim is not that the product is squarefree. for c: if $A=PTP^{-1}$, then $A^2=(PTP^{-1})(PTP^{-1})$...

Comment: Ok, so c. is true. Could you help me with b. and c. ?

Answer (score 0):

The sentence "$P_a$ is a product of polynomials of degree one" is ambiguous, but most likely it means only that $P_a$ can be written $\Pi_{i=1}^n(x-\lambda_i)$, where the $\lambda_i$ need not be distinct. In other words, the same linear factor is allowed to appear more than once.

Using this interpretation, here is a hint for statements (a) and (b): what form does the characteristic polynomial of an upper triangular matrix take? (You've already noted similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomials. Note also that $T$ has real entries.)

Comment: Hmm, using this interpretation - I think that I shown counterexample

Comment: @J.Doe: no, you are not reading closely. I said "the $\lambda_i$ **need not be distinct**."

Comment: I don't understand you. Why my example is not counter example?

Comment: @J.Doe: I don't know how else to put it. The polynomial $(1-\lambda)(1-\lambda)$ **is**, in fact, "a product of polynomials of degree one" under the interpretation I have adopted. So, under this interpretation, you have not given a counterexample, but rather an example. You are reading too much into the condition: it does not say the polynomial is squarefree. If it did, your example would be a counterexample.

Comment: So only chance for counterexample is finding matrix with characteristic polynomial of degree lower than $n$, yeah ?

Comment: @J.Doe: there is no counterexample, period. Statements (a) and (b) are true, under my interpretation of the statement, because the characteristic polynomial of a real upper triangular matrix does have the form $\Pi_{i=1}^n(x-\lambda_i)$ where the $\lambda_i$ are real but not necessarily distinct.

Comment: Ok, I understand you. Eigenvalues of triangular matrix are values on main diagonality.  Your interpretation requires that matrix contains exactly $n$ eigenvalues. yeah ?

Comment: From what you know that we have real coeffictient ?